# Using datetime in Python and how to import from Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-datetime

In python, I am using the command `start = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` and in Excel I have the date and time as 11/11/2005 12:00:00 AM. When I try to run the code, it is telling me that the time in excel does not match the code. How do I fix this?

Comment: `%H` is for a 24-hour clock and you are passing with an AM/PM.  Change to `''%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'`.  `%I` handles the 12-hour clock and `%p` handles the AM/PM.

Comment: Show some sample code.  See the [mcve] guidelines.  In Excel, a time is a floating point value indicating the number of days since the epoch, so depending on how you fetch the Excel value you might be comparing a string to an float.

Answer (score 1):

Your string representation of your date is a little wrong.

**Try:**

```
import datetime
a = "11/11/2005 12:00:00 AM"
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
print(start)
```

**Output:**

```
2005-11-11 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have managed to get:

[image]

With this code:

```
import xlsxwriter
import datetime

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('myxls.xlsx')
starting = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1',starting)
```